# Apache serves certificate from different domain

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a server with an Apache (2.4.25) webserver for multiple domains and their subdomains.

Currently I configured every VirtualHost File with the same structure, generated a SSL certificate for every domain/subdomain via certbot. All of my websites work proberly except one.

VirtualHost (:80 and :443 are in seperate files)

```
<VirtualHost domain2.org:80>
    ServerName domain2.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.org

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.*
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost domain2.org:443>
    ServerName domain2.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.org

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.org/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.org/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

I created the certificates with the following command:

```
certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/domain2.org -d domain2.org
```

Given I have the following domains:

```
domain1.org
sub.domain1.org
domain2.org
sub.domain2.org
domain3.org
```

Then when I want to visit `domain2.org` with Firefox (59.0.3) I get an certificate mismatch. It says that the server send the certificate for `sub.domain1.org`.

Additional info: `sub.domain1.org` is the first file in de directory (alphabetically)

Does anybody know what is wrong with my configuration or server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your virtual host definition should be the ports apache is listening on, rather than related to the domain. Specifically this bit:

```
<VirtualHost domain2.org:80>
```

Typically, that's either an IP:PORT, or *:PORT, the latter indicating that you want this vhost to bind to any IP on the system, rather than a defined IP.

Also, this relates to the listen lines you have in (on debian-based systems) /etc/apache2/ports.conf -- they'll be of the form listen 80, listen IP:80, your VirtualHost definition should match that.

Apache is probably resolving domain2.org to your IP address upon initialization, and if your DNS hasn't been updated, or dns cache is still taking effect, it'll resolve to the wrong IP.

To see what ip/ports apache is listening on, and to which ServerName defined vhost it's assigned to each, again on debian-based systems you can use the following command:

```
apache2ctl -S
```

Short form, you probably want your VirtualHost definition as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

or

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

I'm assuming you're running a 'new enough' version of OpenSSL which supports SNI, the technology behind allowing multiple SSL certificates on one server IP address.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even tried this anymore because on sime point in my troubleshooting I tried it and did not work. But now, everything as it should.